# Replacing all special and cyrilic characters appearing in all languages in article Titles with Tridion acceptable charaters

Tags: publishing

Recently we are facing the issue that end users of different countries are creating titles having country specific special characters (like with accent etc.) but since Tridion doesnot allow such characters it is not publishing those articles.We don't want the characters to be lost so either we want to replace those with some valid character or want to keep as it is but need to make sure Tridion accepts those. Could you let me know the best possible way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: In the DialogServer days we used to fix this issue by installing those languages in regional and language options on the server. Perhaps you could try that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Tridion does not allow such characters"? I'm not aware of such restrictions (on titles)

Comment: It sounds like it fails at Publishing, so definitely Tridion is letting you use them (or you wouldn't be able to save them). Are you using these to generate a file name?

Comment: Please give more details of exactly what problems you have encountered. What tests have you done, and what were the results?